# Is it possible to spawn a process inside a thread in Python?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm wrting a program that spawns a process and restarts the process on certain conditions. For example, if a child process doesn't send data anymore to the mother process, for a certain period of time, I want the mother process to terminate the child process and restart it. I thought I could use a thread to recieve data from a child process and restart the child process, but it doesn't work the way I thought.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

pipe_in, pipe_out = mp.Pipe()

class Mother():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pipe_out = pipe_out

        self.proc = mp.Process(target = self.test_func, args=(pipe_in, ))
        self.proc.start()

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_reciever, args=(self.pipe_out, ))
        self.thread.start()

    def thread_reciever(self, pipe_out):
        while True:
            value = pipe_out.recv()

            print(value)
            if value == 5:
                self.proc.terminate()
                time.sleep(2)
                self.proc = mp.Process(target = self.test_func)
                self.proc.start()

    def test_func(self, pipe_in):
        for i in range(10):
            pipe_in.send(i)
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = Mother()
```

It prints out this error.

```
D:\>d:\python36-32\python.exe temp06.py
    0
1
2
3
4
5
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "d:\python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "temp06.py", line 28, in thread_reciever
    self.proc.start()
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects


D:\>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87]
```

How could I start and terminate a process inside a thread? (I'm using a thread because it can synchronously recieve data from a different process) Or are there any other ways to do this job?

**test_func as a global function**

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

pipe_in, pipe_out = mp.Pipe()  

def test_func( pipe_in):
    for i in range(10):
        pipe_in.send(i)
        time.sleep(1)

class Mother():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pipe_out = pipe_out
        mp.freeze_support()
        self.proc = mp.Process(target = test_func, args=(pipe_in, ))
        self.proc.start()

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_reciever, args=(self.pipe_out, ))
        self.thread.start()

    def thread_reciever(self, pipe_out):
        while True:
            value = pipe_out.recv()

            print(value)
            if value == 5:
                self.proc.terminate()
                time.sleep(2)
                mp.freeze_support()
                self.proc = mp.Process(target = test_func, args=(pipe_in,))
                self.proc.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    r = Mother()
```

OUTPUT

```
D:\> d:\python36-32\python.exe temp06.py
0
1
2
3
4
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
File "d:\python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'test_func' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: I think that when `self.test_func` is the target, the whole `self` object must be pickled. But on the second process creation there is a thread object in `self.thread` which can't be pickled. Try to store the thread object outside of the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

under windows, as there is no `fork` syscall, python starts a new interpreter instance, use `pickle`/`unpickle` to reconstruct execution context, but `thread.Lock` is not picklable. while pickling `self.test_func`, `self.thread` reference to a `thread.Lock` object, makes it unpicklable.

you could simply change `test_func` to a plain global function, without thread object reference :

```
self.proc = mp.Process(target = test_func, args=(pipe_in,))
...
def test_func(pipe_in):
    for i in range(10):
        pipe_in.send(i)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, my goal is to make the program terminate and execute a new process every 5 seconds, according to the data recieved from its own child process. That's why I used a thread. Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: I simply followed your advice and changed ```test_func``` to a global function, and the error says ```AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'test_func' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>```. Does it mean that it can't find ```test_func``` in the main name space?

Comment: I've added the changed code to my question. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Thank you again! Then maybe it's my laptop.

Comment: @maynull reproduced under python3, but need some time to figure out how to fix.

Comment: @maynull a quick and dirty workaround: move `test_func` to another module, then import to the current script.

Comment: It works fine when the function is imported from a different file. Thank you for the tip. I wonder if it's Python's problem.

Comment: @maynull very likely, the usage here is legit IMO, I would test this under python 3.7 later.